# Simply typed lambda calculus and higher order logic

Tags: lo.logic, typed-lambda-calculus, curry-howard

What is the relation between simply typed lambda calculus and higher order logic?

Under Curry-Howard it seems that simply typed lambda calculus corresponds to propositional logic. How is it related to higher order logic? According to this tutorial by Geuvers: http://typessummerschool07.cs.unibo.it/courses/geuvers-1.pdf the language of HOL seems to be STT. Shouldn't it be PROP? What does that mean?

Did Church have in mind HOL when defined STT?

Comment: Yes, Church did have HOL in mind. The trick to get HOL from STT is to use *equality*, in addition to function application and function abstraction. Then you can write $(\forall x:\alpha.A_*)$ as $(\lambda x:\alpha.A_*)=(\lambda x:\alpha.\top)$, among others. I like "The Seven Virtues of Simple Type Theory" as an introduction to STT, which addresses this sort of questions. Maybe I should write an answer...

Comment: So, when talking about Curry-Howard, what would be the correct logic equivalent to STT? HOL or PROP?

Comment: With respect to Curry-Howard, it don't think it will be HOL. Maybe it's the multiplicative fragment of intuitionistic PROP, i.e. intuitionistic PROP without "or". But that was for CCC (cartesian closed category), and I'm a bit tired at the moment. Lambda will probably be translated as "implication", which was the "exponential" in CCC. The "product" from CCC was "and", so you would need a "pair" in STT for that. And "or" would be a "sum" type in STT then, i.e. a disjoint union, maybe an if "a" then "b" else "c" does that.

Comment: I think I am confusing something (or everything). If STT ~= PROP (via Curry-Howard), and STT is also HOL, then I can use PROP in some sense to have HOL?

Comment: As I said, you use *equality* to get HOL. For STT ~= PROP (via Curry-Howard), you are not allowed to use *equality* in STT. And think about it, *equality* is simply undecidable, so it has to increase the expressive power if you allow it.

Comment: @ThomasKlimpel: you should turn your comments into an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The distinction is this: if STLC is taken as a primitive language at the **type-level** adding constructors and a small number of axioms is sufficient to give you the full expressive power of HOL.

Taking $\iota$ as the base type of numbers ans $\omicron$ as the base type of propositions, you can add the constants
$$ \forall_\tau:(\tau\rightarrow \omicron)\rightarrow \omicron\quad \supset:\omicron\rightarrow\omicron\rightarrow \omicron$$

where $\tau$ is an arbitrary type (so one $\forall$ constant for each type). One possible set of axioms:

$$ \frac{\phi(x)}{\forall_\tau(\lambda x.\phi(x))}\mbox{$x:\tau$ not free in the hypotheses}$$

$$ \frac{\Large{\substack{[\psi]\\ \\ .\\ .\\ .\\ \\ \phi}}}{\psi\supset \phi}$$

where $[\psi]$ means that the hypothesis $\psi$ is *discharged*. Interesting fact: the other connectives $\exists_\tau, \vee$... can be derived from just those 2.

The subtlety is distinguishing between $\lambda$-terms as a way to represent proofs, as predicated by the Curry-Howard-de Bruijn (Martin-Löf) correspondence, or as a way to represent the terms you reason upon. The two views are not incompatible, of course.

In particular there is a typed $\lambda$-calculus that faithfully represents HOL (minus various axioms of course). This happens to be a sub-system of the [Calculus of Constructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_constructions), and is described in detail by Geuvers in [*The Calculus of Constructions and Higher Order Logic*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.35.3947). He also details the differences between the two (the CoC is not a conservative extension of HOL).

Comment: I forgot to note: you can avoid adding $\forall_\tau$ and $\supset$ if you add $=_\tau :\tau\rightarrow\tau\rightarrow\omicron$ along with some clever axioms, which is what Thomas was suggesting.

Comment: What are those clever axioms, please? I guess this has to do with providing a way to prove the equality … Also, do you know a name to explicitly distinguish the levels of HOL extensions? (with equality, then with polymorphic type, then with dependant types).

Comment: @Hibou57 the axioms are outlined in the excellent article [The Seven Virtues of Simple Type Theory](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S157086830700081X). I don't know that there are explicit names to distinguish different extensions of STT, other than the ones you used.